# How to list all dates in a month to create a calendar

Tags: c#, calendar

I have started poking around C# a little bit, and the first challenge I got was creating a type of calendar. Its rather easy to type 1, 2, 3, 4.. till'
 you got the dates you need, but since that will then be fixed, it will be incorrect for some months. I have tried searching everywhere, but right now I can't find anything that would help me, because it either only gives me the amount of days in the month, printing a load of 30's, or I don't get it to work. 
As of right now I have a for loop that seems to be working, looping from 1, to the end of the month. I also have a list, but inside that list I need to know how to print the days in order to achieve what I am going for.

```
<%      

            var days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2015, 11);

            for (int i = 1; i < days; i++)
            {
                Response.Write("<div class='week'>");
                 Response.Write("<ul>");
                    Response.Write("<li>");

                    Response.Write(days);           

                     Response.Write("</li>");
                    Response.Write("</ul>");
                Response.Write("</div>");
            }


             %>
```

This is what I have right now, but all it does is print 30 30 times, and while I have tried other things, this is the closest thing I have gotten to it this far.

Comment: Well `DateTime.DaysInMonth` may be what you're looking for, but it's hard to tell without knowing more about what you're doing with the information. If you could show us the code that's not working, it would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet I seem to be good at forgetting to include code. There!

Comment: Hint: you're not using `i` in your loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet Kind of confused me there, to be fair, hehe

Comment: Which part is confusing? Nowhere in the body of the loop do you use `i`, so I'm not surprised that the output of the loop is the same for each iteration. There's nothing calendar-specific here... it's really just a matter of writing the loop properly.

Comment: @Xariez:- You are using `Response.Write(days);` everytime in your loop which should be like `Response.Write(i);`

Comment: @JonSkeet  - If you want to be marked as a answer, go ahead and put it as one. As someone who has some (but not to much) knowledge from PHP, and barely any in C#, i'm personally not surprised I missed that, still though. Cheers for your help. When I said that you confused me, I didn't get what you ment by "you're not using i in your loop" because of some reason I thought it would have worked like i had it.

Comment: @RahulTripathi Same reply as above to JonSkeet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ you can try like this:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))  
          .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day)).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

As commented above by Jon you have not used the variable i in your loop, so you need,

```
Response.Write(i);
```

instead of

```
Response.Write(days);
```